# Properly summing up calendar days in double day shift - Excel

Tags: excel, formula, modulo, dataformat

[situations preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk034.png)

So on screen I made there are bunch of projects, operations needed to performed, and time between operations in Calendar days. I need to show difference in integer value, eventually number with point five My problem is following: 
When I subtract data of Operation 1 from Operation 9, my outcome should equals to added differences between particular operations. My problem is that we work on 2 shifts, so I made thanks to @teylyn following formula (for C4 cell):

```
=ROUNDDOWN(C2-B2;0)+IF(MOD(C2-B2;1)>0,6;1;IF(MOD(C2-B2;1)>0,2;0,5;0))-IF(OR(AND(HOUR(B2)=22;HOUR(C2)=14);AND(HOUR(B2)=14;HOUR(C2)=6));0,5;0)
```

This gives much better results, but as I marked on red, has some inaccuracy. I would be grateful for any idea.

Comment: You are rounding to the nearest half hour, which potentially introduces a rounding error in the calculation.  That rounding error will be propagated to the total.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? I thought rounddown function rounds to the nearest integer, but going backwards